# Only some locally built Docker images fail to work on remote server (error: "No command specified")

Tags: linux, docker

I have a perplexing Docker problem. I am running Docker on my Mint laptop and on a Ubuntu VPS. I have been able to build images in the past locally and send them to the server and have them run there. However, for clarity, the ones that work were probably built when I was running Ubuntu locally (more on that later).

I have an example based on Alpine:

```
FROM alpine:3.5

# Do a system update
RUN apk update

ENTRYPOINT ["sleep", "3"]
```

I build like so, and send to the remote:

```
docker build -t alpine-sleep .
docker save alpine-sleep | gzip > alpine-sleep.tgz
rsync --progress alpine-sleep.tgz myserver.example.com:/path/to/images/
```

I then unpack/import on the remote, and run, thus:

```
docker import /path/to/images/alpine-sleep.tgz alpine-sleep
docker run -it alpine-sleep
```

I get this console reply:

> docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.
>   See 'docker run --help'.

However, if I copy the Dockerfile to the remote, then do this:

```
docker build -t alpine-sleep-localbuild .
docker run -it alpine-sleep-localbuild
```

then I get the `sleep` working fine.

My Docker and kernel versions locally:

```
jon@jvb ~/alpine_test $ uname -r
4.4.0-79-generic
jon@jvb ~/alpine_test $ docker -v
Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802
```

And remotely:

```
root@vps:~/alpine-sleep# uname -r
3.13.0-24-generic
root@vps:~/alpine-sleep# docker -v
Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be
```

I wonder, does the major difference in the kernel make a difference? I expect 3.13 to 4.4 is quite a big jump. I don't recall what version of the kernel I was using when I build things when I was running Ubuntu locally, but it would not surprise me if it is was 3.x.

The other thing that strikes me as unexpected is the high variation in Docker version numbers. How do I have version 1.x locally, and 17.x remotely? Has the project been through a version re-numbering?

### Update

I've just checked the kernel version when I was running Ubuntu locally, and that was:

```
4.4.0-75-generic
```

So, this makes me think that a major kernel discrepancy could not be to blame.

Comment: Where is your command to create the alpine-sleep.tgz?

Comment: Edited in @BMitch, good catch. It's `docker save alpine-sleep | gzip > alpine-sleep.tgz`.

Comment: On the version numbers, docker went from 1.13.1 to 17.03 with a reworking of their version numbering. https://blog.docker.com/2017/03/docker-enterprise-edition/

Comment: Can you post any difference in both versions (import vs build) with the following commands? `docker history alpine-sleep` and `docker inspect alpine-sleep`, **both in remote VPS**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that Docker won't warn you when you use the wrong combination of save/load and export/import. You save/load an image, and you export/import a tar file from a container. Since you are doing a `docker save` to save your image, you need to do a `docker load` to restore it on the other host:

```
docker load < /path/to/images/alpine-sleep.tgz
```

Comment: You're right. As mnemonic one can use the opposite of the common sense. Save and load for something that is already saved (images), and export/import for something that need to be saved (container state)

Comment: Once I read this, I had an "aha" moment. Thanks! This fixed it, confirmed by trying it just now. Based on your experience with Docker, is it understandable/sensible that there is no warning here? I want the raw image with no runtime-accumulated layer FS stuff on top. Perhaps only an error message tweak is necessary: "import is for exported containers, are you sure this is not an image?".

Comment: @halfer from Robert's link, it looks like there isn't an easy way to check the tar file to warn of mixing these commands that won't break other stuff.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Now I know the answer, I am better able to search for [this having happened before](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-save-and-import-does-not-work/26456). Looks like it's been raised on Robert's link as well. I've been resisting looking into a registry, but I wonder if I should move that to my more-likely-to-do list `:-)`.

Answer (score 2):

I have found this very old issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1826

> An image imported via docker import won't know what command to run. Any image will lose all of its associated metadata on export, so the default command won't be available after importing it somewhere else.

So, run it with the entrypoint:

```
docker run --entrypoint sleep alpine-sleep 3
```

Comment: Nice find. All the more reason to share images using a registry instead of import/export.

Comment: I agree, good find Robert, and thanks. However I have Docker images that _have_ worked by transferring them manually without a registry.